# Concatenate ImmutableSet using Guava

Tags: java, linq, guava

I am used to C# where we have `IEnumerable<T>.SelectMany` but find myself dabbling in some Java code using Google's Guava library. Is there an equivalent to SelectMany in Guava?

Example: 
If I have a stream/map construct like this

```
collections
            .stream()
            .map(collection -> loadKeys(collection.getTenant(), collection.getGroup()))
            .collect(GuavaCollectors.immutableSet());
```

where `loadKeys` returns something like `ImmutableSet<String>`, this function would return `ImmutableSet<ImmutableSet<String>>` but I want to just flatten them into one `ImmutableSet<String>`

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) method :

```
collections
        .stream()
        .flatMap(collection -> loadKeys(collection.getTenant(), collection.getGroup()).stream())
        .collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
```

Notice that you get the `stream` out of `loadKeys` method result. The result from this should be `ImmutableSet<String>` assuming that `loadKeys` returns a Set.

Comment: That extra `stream()` was what I am missing. Thank you!